# update each row (sql server) based on subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update each row of table1->keyField based on table2 value

Table1

```
Id|keyField

1|test_500

2|test_501

3|test_501
```

500,501 are primary key of and my another table2

Table2

```
Id|value

500|A

501|B

502|C
```

I have tried something like

```
update table1 set keyField=(select value from table2 where id=substring(expression))
```

but my select return multiple statement so unable to run the query.
any help or direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the syntax like this

```
 UPDATE table1 SET keyField = Table2.Value 
 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 
 ON table1.Id = substring(expression))
```

Comment: many many thanks @srp , your sugesstion worked. you are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, this might be what you need:

```
UPDATE T1 SET
    keyField = T2.Value
FROM
    Table1 AS T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T2.id = SUBSTRING(T1.keyField, 6, 100)
```

Careful when comparing substring result with an numeric value, might get a conversion error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (necessary notes are in comments below):

```
--generate some sample data (the same as you provided)
declare @table1 table (id int, keyField varchar(10))
insert into @table1 values (1,'test_500'),(2,'test_501'),(3,'test_502')
declare @table2 table (id int, value char(1))
insert into @table2 values (500,'A'),(501,'B'),(502,'C')
--in case you want to see tables first
--select * from @table1
--select * from @table2

--here you extract the number in first table in keyField column and match it with ID from second table, upon that, you update first table
update @table1 set keyField = value from @table2 [t2]
where cast(right(keyfield, len(keyfield) - charindex('_',keyfield)) as int) = [t2].id

select * from @table1
```